# T-SQL: Round to nearest 15 minute interval

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

What's the best way to round an HH:MM value to the closest 15 minute interval?  I don't track seconds so they don't matter.

```
00:08:00 becomes 00:15:00 
00:07:00 becomes 00:00:00 
01:59:00 becomes 02:00:00
```

and so on. Is there an elegant, non UDF or Case statement method for doing this?

**EDIT:** Here's the SQL I'm using to get the above values that I'd like to round:

```
CONVERT(CHAR(8), DATEADD(n, SUM(DATEDIFF(n, starttime, stoptime)), 0), 108)
```

`starttime` and `stoptime` are SQL `datetime`s.

Comment: Which data type do you have the value stored as?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829825/how-to-re-format-datetime-in-sql-with-ceiling-or-flooring-method/829927#829927

Comment: @Tomalak - It's a SUM of DATEDIFFed datetimes converted to HH:MM:SS.  I've been piecing it together from crap i've found online.  I'll update the question with my SQL

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This was answered here [How to Round a Time in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249794/how-to-round-a-time-in-t-sql) and i think it should work for you to.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[RoundTime] (@Time datetime, @RoundTo float) RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @RoundedTime smalldatetime, @Multiplier float

    SET @Multiplier = 24.0 / @RoundTo

    SET @RoundedTime= ROUND(CAST(CAST(CONVERT(varchar, @Time, 121) AS datetime) AS float) * @Multiplier, 0) / @Multiplier

    RETURN @RoundedTime
END

-- Usage    
SELECT dbo.RoundTime('13:15', 0.5)
```

Comment: I saw that and thought it was overkill.  Just thought there should be a simpler approach when I don't care about hours or seconds.  I just want to take a number between 0 and 60, and round it appropriately to quarter hour.  I'll take another look at the previous answer.

Comment: Well, not exactly what I was looking for, but at least now I have a flexible UDF that solves this problem and potentialy future ones.

Answer (score 91):

I am currently using a dateadd / datediff variant with a zero (0) date for this. No Casting required:

```
select dateadd(minute, datediff(minute,0,GETDATE()) / 15 * 15, 0)
```

GETDATE() is whatever your datetime is.

This will work for dates at least up to the year 5500 before the datediff failes because of an overflow. However if you try to use second accuracy, above will fail right away.

Using another fixed date, like '2009-01-01', or Today's date (warning, more ugly SQL) will fix that. A future date will also work. As long as it has a time part of 00:00:00 you can base another datetime on it.

for example: round to the nearest 30 seconds:

```
select dateadd(second, round(datediff(second, '2010-01-01', GETDATE()) / 30.0, 0) * 30, '2010-01-01');
```

Comment: This is a good solution, better than the accepted one (complexity- and speed- wise)

Comment: The top method works well, but it truncates, rather than rounding, e.g. select dateadd(minute, datediff(minute,0,'2015-05-22T17:29:00') / 15 * 15, 0) returns 2015-05-22 17:15:00.000

Comment: You can easily figure out the rest of needed logic with just adding a modulus operator to get the remainder and adding a case logic: Declare @Dt DateTime = '2016-01-01 14:22:30' --change to test

select CASE WHEN (DATEPART(MINUTE, @Dt) % 15) * 60 + DATEPART(SECOND, @Dt) < 450 THEN  DATEADD(minute, datediff(minute,0, @Dt) / 15 * 15, 0)
  ELSE DATEADD(minute, (DATEDIFF(minute,0, @Dt) / 15 * 15) + 15, 0) END

Comment: Dito @StephenOberauer, ** WARNING THIS SOLUTION TRUNCATES ** This does not round to the nearest 15 minutes, it chops it off to the next lowest 15-minute interval.

Comment: Do the standard "cheat" for rounding with truncation.  Add half the value you want, then truncate.  SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, (DATEADD(SECOND, (60 * 7.5), GETDATE()))) / 15 * 15, 0) -- this is the main part: DATEADD(SECOND, (60 * 7.5), GETDATE())

Comment: Its efficient and clean to do "/ 15 * 15"
+1 worked perfect, at least as the software wont last for 5500 year

Answer (score 40):

I know this is a old post but wanted to share my answer.  This builds on @hbrowser response. Here is what I've come up with.  This will round up or down to the nearest 15 minutes.

```
SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, ROUND(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, GETDATE()) / 15.0, 0) * 15, 0);
```

> By doing this logic inline, rather than inside a user defined function, over large recordsets you should experience greater performance.
>
> You can change the way rounding occurs by swapping the `ROUND` function to use `FLOOR` or `CAST expr AS INT` to always round down or use `CEILING` to always round up.

Your individual use case will determine what style of rounding you may need to use.

The following script can be used to observe the differences offered by the different rounding techniques:

> NOTE: to simplify the output each result has been casted to TIME(0), this is only done to simplify the output for this particular example.

```
DECLARE @SequenceStart SmallDateTime = CAST(GETDATE() AS Date); 
DECLARE @SequenceEnd SmallDateTime = DateAdd(HOUR, 2, @SequenceStart); -- Recursive CTEs should always have an upper limit
DECLARE @SequenceIntMins INT = 5; -- increment by 5 to show the difference with rounding
WITH TimeSequence([Time]) as
(
    SELECT @SequenceStart as [Time]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DateAdd(MINUTE, 5, [Time]) FROM TimeSequence 
    WHERE [Time] <= @SequenceEnd
)
    SELECT [Time] = Cast([Time] as TIME(0))
    , Rounded = CAST(DATEADD(MINUTE, ROUND(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, [Time]) / 15.0, 0) * 15, 0) as TIME(0))
    , Casted = CAST(DATEADD(MINUTE, CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, [Time]) / 15.0 AS INT) * 15, 0) as TIME(0))
    , Floored = CAST(DATEADD(MINUTE, FLOOR(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, [Time]) / 15.0) * 15, 0) as TIME(0))
    , Ceilinged = CAST(DATEADD(MINUTE, CEILING(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, [Time]) / 15.0) * 15, 0) as TIME(0))
FROM TimeSequence OPTION ( MaxRecursion 1000);
-- MaxRecursion may be neccessary if you change the interval or end of the sequence
```

```
Time        Rounded     Casted      Floored     Ceilinged
00:00:00    00:00:00    00:00:00    00:00:00    00:00:00
00:05:00    00:00:00    00:00:00    00:00:00    00:15:00
00:10:00    00:15:00    00:00:00    00:00:00    00:15:00
00:15:00    00:15:00    00:15:00    00:15:00    00:15:00
00:20:00    00:15:00    00:15:00    00:15:00    00:30:00
00:25:00    00:30:00    00:15:00    00:15:00    00:30:00
00:30:00    00:30:00    00:30:00    00:30:00    00:30:00
00:35:00    00:30:00    00:30:00    00:30:00    00:45:00
00:40:00    00:45:00    00:30:00    00:30:00    00:45:00
00:45:00    00:45:00    00:45:00    00:45:00    00:45:00
00:50:00    00:45:00    00:45:00    00:45:00    01:00:00
00:55:00    01:00:00    00:45:00    00:45:00    01:00:00
01:00:00    01:00:00    01:00:00    01:00:00    01:00:00
01:05:00    01:00:00    01:00:00    01:00:00    01:15:00
```

Comment: I think you should explicitly state in your answer what makes it _different_ from [@hbrowser's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1624984/241211) (i.e. Yours uses `ROUND`, while his/hers does an implicit `FLOOR` with integer division).

Comment: This is the better answer.  @hbrower's will turn 7:59pm into 7:45pm.  This one rounds up to 8pm

Comment: This is an incredibly useful little formula, especially with the ease of swapping out `round` for `floor` or `celing` 

Answer (score 7):

You can round a date to the nearest quarter like:

```
cast(floor(cast(getdate() as float(53))*24*4)/(24*4) as datetime)
```

Casting datetime to double precesion to avoid overflows, double = float(53).  Multiply by 24*4, the number of quarters in a day.  Round to the nearest multiple of quarters with floor(), and then divide by 24*4 to convert back to normal time.

Comment: Just so we're clear, this does not round to the nearest quarter. The floor() always makes it the last quarter that just occurred. In order to get the nearest quarter, you'd have to replace that with the round() function with a precision of 0.

Answer (score 5):

Tried Andomar's answer and there was rounding issues at 30 and 00 - so a few tweaks and this works perfectly:

```
cast(round(floor(cast(getdate() as float(53))*24*4)/(24*4),5) as smalldatetime)
```

This will show the last 15 minute increment, not the nearest, i.e. it won't go forward which is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 4):

Okay easiest way:

convert the minutes to a decimal number by dividing by 60.

```
8/60 = 0.1333333333333333
```

multiply by 4

```
0.1333333333333333 * 4   = 0.5333333333333333
```

Round the product:

```
Round(0.5333333333333333,0) = 1
```

divide the round number by 4

```
1/4 = 0.25 = 15 minutes
```

if you want the minutes just multiply it by 60

```
0.25*60 = 15
```

Give a man a fish....

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Declare @Dt DateTime 
Set @Dt = getDate()

Select DateAdd(minute, 
        15 * ((60 * Datepart(hour, @Dt) + 
        Datepart(Minute, @Dt)+ 
        Case When DatePart(second, @Dt) < 30 
        Then 7 Else 8 End) / 15),
    DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 0, @Dt), 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @t time  ='00:51:00.000' 
DECLARE @m  int = DATEPART(MI,@t)%15

-- 2008
SELECT DATEADD(mi,CASE WHEN @m >=8 THEN 15-@m ELSE -1*@m END,@t)

-- 2012
SELECT DATEADD(mi,IIF(@m >=8,15-@m,-1*@m),@t)
```

Answer (score 1):

--This is my favorite way to round time

```
DECLARE @Time DATETIME = GETDATE()
       ,@RoundInterval INT = 30  --in minutes, needs to be a number that can be divided evenly into 60
       ,@RoundDirection INT = 2  --0 is down to the last interval, 1 is to the nearest interval, 2 is up to the next interval

SELECT  DATEADD(MINUTE,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,0,DATEADD(SECOND,30*@RoundDirection*@RoundInterval,@Time))/@RoundInterval*@RoundInterval,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create function RoundQuarterHour
(
    @dt datetime
)
returns datetime
as
begin
    declare @result datetime
    declare @mm int
    set @mm=datepart(minute,@dt)
    set @result = dateadd(minute,-@mm + (round(@mm/cast(15 as float),0)*15) , @dt )

    return @result
end
go


           select dbo.RoundQuarterHour('2009-may-5 20:00') , '00'
 union all select dbo.RoundQuarterHour('2009-may-5 20:01') , '01'
 union all select dbo.RoundQuarterHour('2009-may-5 20:07') , '07'
 union all select dbo.RoundQuarterHour('2009-may-5 20:08') , '08'
 union all select dbo.RoundQuarterHour('2009-may-5 20:22') , '22'
 union all select dbo.RoundQuarterHour('2009-may-5 20:23') , '23'
 union all select dbo.RoundQuarterHour('2009-may-5 20:37') , '37'
 union all select dbo.RoundQuarterHour('2009-may-5 20:38') , '38'
 union all select dbo.RoundQuarterHour('2009-may-5 20:52') , '52'
 union all select dbo.RoundQuarterHour('2009-may-5 20:53') , '53'
 union all select dbo.RoundQuarterHour('2009-may-5 20:59') , '59'
```

Answer (score 0):

Time rounding in T-SQL is actually very problematic and many times inaccurate.

Years ago, I moved all rounding of times into code vs. using all the extra hub-bub one has to do in T-SQL to make it happen and to happen accurately. Rounding times in code is easier and much more accurate.

If you're stuck in T-SQL and have no supporting code, or don't have access to that code, then follow the examples previously mentioned. Otherwise, I humbly recommend letting code do the work.

Answer (score 0):

how about this one? (variable added for readability)

```
create function dbo.FloorTimeToQuarters
(
 @dt as datetime
)
RETURNS datetime
as

BEGIN

 DECLARE @timeAsInt bigint
 SET @timeAsInt = ( cast( @dt as float ) * 96 )
 RETURN DateAdd( hour, @timeAsInt % 96, cast( @timeAsInt / 96 as datetime)  )

END
```

Answer (score 0):

To set block in 15 minutes:

```
CREATE FUNCTION RoundQuarterHour (
    @dt DATETIME
) RETURNS DATETIME

AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @date DATETIME
    SET @date = CONVERT(varchar(16),@dt,121) --Sin segundos, ni milisegundos
    RETURN DATEADD(MINUTE,(DATEPART(MINUTE,@date) % 15)*-1, @date)
END

PRINT dbo.RoundQuarterHour('2011/01/01 18:00:07')  --Jan  1 2011  6:00PM
PRINT dbo.RoundQuarterHour('2011/01/01 18:01:07')  --Jan  1 2011  6:00PM
PRINT dbo.RoundQuarterHour('2011/01/01 18:13:07')  --Jan  1 2011  6:00PM
PRINT dbo.RoundQuarterHour('2011/01/01 18:14:07')  --Jan  1 2011  6:00PM
PRINT dbo.RoundQuarterHour('2011/01/01 18:15:07')  --Jan  1 2011  6:15PM
PRINT dbo.RoundQuarterHour('2011/01/01 18:16:07')  --Jan  1 2011  6:15PM
```

Answer (score 0):

This will round to the nearest 15 minutes.  You can modify @ROUND to the interval of your choice.

```
Declare @Dt DateTime = '2016-01-01 14:38:00' 
DECLARE @ROUND int = 15;
SELECT
CASE WHEN (DATEPART(MINUTE, @Dt) % @ROUND) * 60 + DATEPART(SECOND, @Dt) < (30 * @ROUND)
THEN DATEADD(minute, datediff(minute,0, @Dt) / @ROUND * @ROUND, 0) 
ELSE DATEADD(minute, (DATEDIFF(minute,0, @Dt) / @ROUND * @ROUND) + @ROUND, 0) 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Premise breaks down to figuring out what increment you want, what's that as a percent of 60 minutes...then figure out the needed number of increments to get there...take the INT value (this chops off remainders) and there you have it, a simple function to round Up or down to the closest increment.

Simple function:

```
    ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[RoundOffDateTime]
(
    @IncDate    DATETIME,
    @Increment  INT
)
RETURNS SMALLDATETIME
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @IncrementPercent DECIMAL(2,2) = CAST(@Increment as decimal)/60
    DECLARE @IncMinutes REAL = ROUND(CAST(DATEPART(mi,@IncDate) as decimal)/CAST(@Increment as decimal),0)
    DECLARE @MinutesNeeded INT = CAST(@IncMinutes * @Increment as INT)

    RETURN CAST(DATEADD(mi,@MinutesNeeded,DATEADD(ss,-DATEPART(ss,@IncDate),DATEADD(mi,-DATEPART(mi,@IncDate),@IncDate))) as smalldatetime)

END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    DECLARE   @Date             DATETIME = GETDATE()

    SELECT    @Date
            , DATEADD(ms, 900000 - DATEDIFF(ms, CAST(@Date AS DATE), @Date) % 900000, @Date)
```