# c# library for data aggregation?

Tags: c#, .net, math

I have weather data which comes at random intervals, from minutes to hours. I need to process the data.

What library (or approach) can be used to aggregate the data into equidistant intervals, e.g. 15 mins, or 1 hr using algorithm like weighted average (preferably, this should be configurable)?

Also, the data may have gaps longer than the output intervals - what algorithms could be applied to fill the gaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use quarters since 01.01.0001 to partition data.

```
int quarters = (int)((eventDate - new DateTime(1, 1, 1)).TotalMinutes / 15);
```

And the interpolation you look for is probably [linear interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation).

Comment: This is what I am working on now. It's a relatively big task. I hoped there is a ready to use library.

Comment: well for clustering/partitioning it does not seem so big, but linear interpolation of data to extract missing data, without using third party libraries can be some work yes...

Answer (score 1):

maybe you want to have a look at this:

http://esper.codehaus.org/

Answer (score 0):

If you are already (or willing to...) persist the data through MS SQL then you can use something like this: [T-SQL: Round to nearest 15 minute interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/830792/t-sql-round-to-nearest-15-minute-interval)