# SQL Server - Combining results from a single query

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Using SQL server 2008R2 I'm attempting to write a query that will return a sum of all values within a specific time frame (in this case in 15min intervals) In the long run this will be used to identify missing data (each server should be returning a value of 12 per 15mins). I've gotten to the point where i get results that im looking for but i need a way to combine them all in the same query. Code Below (date will normally be defined by a variable, using 09/01/2013 as an example in this case):

```
Select SUM(Accounted_for) 'accounted for',date,time,server
from dbmetrics.dbo.tblmissing 
where DATE='09/01/2013'
  and (TIME between '00:00:00' and '23:59:59')
  and SERVER='Server01'
group by DATE, TIME, server , DATEPART(hour,time),
      DATEPART(MINUTE,time),DATEPART(second,time) / 96
GO
```

Results return along the lines of this"
Results that come back look like this

```
Number    Date            Time                   Server
4         2013-09-01      12:00:01.0000000      server01
6         2013-09-01      12:00:02.0000000      server01
2         2013-09-01      12:00:15.0000000      server01
10        2013-09-01      12:15:02.0000000      server01
2         2013-09-01      12:15:09.0000000      server01
```

What I would like to see would be

```
12      2013-09-01      12:00:00.0000      Server01
12      2013-09-01      12:15:00.0000      Server01
```

Comment: Your choice of sample data is poor. The minute of every data point happens to conveniently land on a 15-minute interval minute, and both time frames coincidentally add up to 12. Can you include a couple of rows like `12:03:26.0000000` and make sure the sums don't match?

Comment: Also, is there any reason the date and time components are stored separately?

Comment: If you will need to round to the nearest 15 minute interval, you may want to look into something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/830792/t-sql-round-to-nearest-15-minute-interval).

Comment: This is based off data that comes in reporting uptimes every 15 minutes. The total number of checks that comes back is 12. What im trying to accomplish is a way to calculate missing numbers (ones that werent run, script failures etc...)

Comment: Even more reason why the sums shouldn't match, right? If you're trying to identify missing data, why doesn't your question even mention that?

Comment: Good point, i've updated the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to `GROUP BY` the `[Server]` rather than get the `MAX()` of `[Server]`. As [Aaron Bertrand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61305/aaron-bertrand) mentions above, it just happens that your time values land on 15 minute intervals. This query will round the time to the minute and group your data as such.

```
SELECT SUM([Number]) AS [Number], 
       [Date], 
       CONVERT(time, DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, 0, [Time]), 0)) AS [Time], 
       MAX([Server]) 
FROM   [Table] 
GROUP  BY [Date], 
          DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, 0, [Time]), 0)
```

[See a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c8e47/5)