# Grouping a time field into 5 minute periods in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a column of times and want to create a second column to show which 5 minute interval on a 24 hr clock they fall into. For example

```
15:19:52 becomes 15:15:00
15:20:11 becomes 15:20:00
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the following. It builds the time

```
SELECT TIMEFROMPARTS(
         DATEPART(HOUR, yourTimeField),
         DATEPART(MINUTE, yourTimeField) / 5 * 5, 0,
         0,
         0)
FROM yourTable
```

[Link to SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/34f73/4)

Comment: nice. didn't know about that. ( oh ok. i use 2008 haha)

Comment: @RoyiNamir: There is no `TIMEFROMPARTS` in 2008 (I do too) but you could improvise like `SELECT CAST(DATEPART(HOUR, yourTimeField) as CHAR(2))+':'+ CAST((DATEPART(MINUTE, yourTimeField) / 5 * 5) as CHAR(2))+':00' as TimeIntervalFive
FROM times`

Comment: @Edper my solution is also flexible where you can do more fine tuning in order to decide on which step to fall. ( off line comment) / but it's much heavier solution :-)

Comment: Your solution is a very good one by the way although as you say 'heavier' one.

Answer (score 1):

There is a thread I found that may help you begin getting started with this.

[T-SQL: Round to nearest 15 minute interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/830792/t-sql-round-to-nearest-15-minute-interval)

However, all the examples here only seem to round up, so you'd need to subtract 5 from the result to get what appears to be what you are seeking.

Comment: The minute interval is adjustable to any number, so don't be mislead by the title.

Comment: This is more appropriate as a comment.

Comment: When I get my 50 rep, i will be glad to do so :)

Comment: @PWilliams0530 here take 10 :-)

Answer (score 0):

Another simplified solution is to create time line and find your exact location :

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (b  TIME)


INSERT INTO @t
VALUES   (  '14:16') ,( '15:19:52') ,('15:20:11')


;
WITH cte AS (
         SELECT CAST ('00:00'AS TIME) AS a
         UNION ALL
         SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, 5, a) from cte
         WHERE  cte.a   <  CAST ('23:54:00' AS TIME)
     )
SELECT * FROM @t CROSS APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 a FROM cte WHERE  a<=b ORDER BY
       a         DESC) k  option (maxrecursion 0)




b   a
14:16:00.0000000    14:15:00.0000000
15:19:52.0000000    15:15:00.0000000
15:20:11.0000000    15:20:00.0000000
```