# extracting data every 15 mins in sql queries

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT dateadd(MINUTE,datediff(MINUTE,-15,Time),15) AS Time,
       round(avg(Amount),1) AS Amount,
       round(avg(Amount2),1) AS Amount2
INTO downt
FROM ee3
JOIN ee4 
     ON DownLine1=DownLine2 --Where Time Null
GROUP BY datediff(MINUTE, -15,Time)
ORDER BY time DESC;

SELECT *
FROM downt;
```

So I have it at a point where I am able to extract and group the data by every 30 mins. But my question is why does this query not give me data for every 15 mins? The script I have provided is part of a larger script that is just running a stored procedure and the timestamp that it provides is just localtimestamp. The script above does all the work.

[image]

Comment: As a guess it doesn't return every 15 minute interval because the data doesn't exist in your tables. From what you posted there is little to no chance anybody can really help. We would need to know the table structures and the data. Without that the best we can do is guess. Try this link as a great starting place. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I cannot do that since the data is under company privacy. What I have provided is enough to point out the faults in the query in my opinion since I can assure you that the query I provided above literally does what is says. The only difference between the data that is there before the query runs is the time is in localTimeStamp and the amount and amount2 are just valuesAsFloats. The fault lies in my query above with me combining dateadd(xx,datediff,xx).

Comment: I of course understand about sensitive data. Nobody would want that. And no what you provided is not enough information. It has nothing to do with DATEADD. That will return certain values. What you want is more rows. If you don't have that data in the table you can't get it back out. Maybe you can create a calendar or time table as the base table for your query. Without some kind of details we just have nothing to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing a bit from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1624984/1225845), and presuming I understand your question correctly, I would suggest something like the following:

```
SELECT dateadd(minute, datediff(minute,0,Time) / 15 * 15, 0) AS Time,
       round(avg(Amount),1) AS Amount,
       round(avg(Amount2),1) AS Amount2
INTO downt
FROM ee3
JOIN ee4 
     ON DownLine1=DownLine2 --Where Time Null
GROUP BY dateadd(minute, datediff(minute,0,Time) / 15 * 15, 0)
ORDER BY time DESC;

SELECT *
FROM downt;
```

Comment: It did not work, however I appreciate the response. The problem is still occurring. However I do see that the first data point that occurred was today at 12:45 and then today at 1:00 but after that it increases by 30 min interval. The main data that my query is manipulating occurs randomly. So its datetime is whenever it gets a ping from the external source.