# how to Round Time(7) Datatype to nearest 15 minutes

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to round the Time(7) data into nearest 15 minutes I used below codes (in report code section) for that but unfortunately this gave me an error in report. can anyone please help me with this.

```
Public Function RoundTime(ByVal dtTime as DateTime) as DateTime

IF (IsNothing(dtTime)) Then
 Return Nothing
END IF 

Dim returnVal as DateTime
Dim nMinutes as Integer
nMinutes = 15 - Minute(dtTime) MOD 15
IF (nMinutes > 7) THEN
 returnVal = DATEADD("n", nMinutes-15, dtTime)
ELSE 
 returnVal = DATEADD("n", nMinutes, dtTime)
END IF
Return returnVal

End Function
```

Comment: Asked and answered previously I believe. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/830792/t-sql-round-to-nearest-15-minute-interval

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's considered polite around here to share what previous attempts you've made at solving your problem, and what errors you've get from them. In this particular post, it'll be very good if you copied the error you received.

Comment: I am trying to get the result in report using below code

Comment: I am trying to get the result in report using this code code.RoundTime(Fields!.value) when I run the program it gave me now error in runtime but int the report it shows as "#error"