# SQL Converting Time to Half Hour Increments and Extracting only HH:MM

Tags: sql

I need to show a report that counts sessions in half hour increments for a 24 hour period.  I used the following case statement and it works well to convert the minutes in the date field.

```
case when datepart (mi,"tablename.name") < 30 
then dateadd(hh, datediff(hh, 0, "tablename.name")+0, 0) else dateadd (mi, 30, 
dateadd(hh, datediff(hh, 0, "tablename.name")+0, 0)) end,
```

Now I am having trouble just pulling out the hh:mm.  I tried this, but it just gives me two additional columns.

```
DATEPART(HH,"tablename.name") AS 'Start_Hour',
DATEPART(minute,"tablename.name") AS 'Start_Min'
```

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. Those date/time functions used are product specific.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CAST(DATEPART(Hour,"tablename.name") as char(2)) + ':' + 
CAST(DATEPART(minute,"tablename.name") as char(2)) As Start_Time
```

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful for getting the time into one field, I need to also show the minutes as either 0 or 30.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is in T-SQL, you can use [format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql) to take care of the string formatting:

```
select format(
  dateadd(minute, round(datediff(minute, '2010-01-01', "tablename.name") / 30, 0)*30, '2010-01-01')
  , N'hh\:mm') 
      from ...
```

Rounding to nearest interval was adapted from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1624984/2109767).

Comment: Thank you Jeremy, I think this almost gets me there, I just need to either show AM/PM or show in 24 hour format.

Comment: Use ```hh:mm tt``` to get AM/PM