# Group data by interval of 15 minutes and use cross tab

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to write a query based on datetime and weekday in sql server where my output should be like :

[image]

My table descriptions are:

```
   **Branch**(DateKey integer,
   BranchName varchar2(20),
   TransactionDate datetime,
   OrderCount integer)

   **Date**(DateKey integer PrimaryKey,
   DayNameofWeek varchar2(15))
```

This is the raw data I have

[image: Data]

Comment: Here is a very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/830792/t-sql-round-to-nearest-15-minute-interval The only Difference is that you would be rounding to the next 15min DOWN and in this question it is directly rounded to the NEXT.

Comment: Do you want to make a query just only for the time duration between 11:30 to 12:30 or there may be more values than that?

Comment: @maulik Its for more than the those values, this is just a sample. I need it for a 24 hour one.

Answer (score 0):

So, this is quite a long shot but I solved it the following way:

I created a `table valued function`, which would take a `date` as a parameter and find all `15-minute` intervals during that day. 
For each day it would go from `00:00, to 00:15, 00:30` up to `23:30, 23:45`, and `23:59`. It also returns each interval `start time` and `end time`, since we will need to use this for every row in your `branch` table to check if they fall into that time slot and if so, count it in.

This is the function:

```
create function dbo.getDate15MinIntervals(@date date)
returns @intervals table (
   [interval] int not null,
   [dayname] varchar(20) not null,
   interval_start_time datetime not null,
   interval_end_time datetime not null
) 
as
begin 

    declare @starttime time = '00:00';
    declare @endtime time = '23:59';

    declare @date_start datetime;
    declare @date_end datetime; 
    declare @min datetime; 

    select @date_start = cast(@date as datetime) + cast(@starttime as datetime), @date_end = cast(@date as datetime) + cast(@endtime as datetime);

    declare  @minutes table ([date] datetime)

    insert into @minutes values (@date_start), (@date_end) -- begin, end of the day

    select @min = DATEADD(mi, 0, @date_start)

    while @min < @date_end
    begin
        select @min = DATEADD(mi, 1, @min)
        insert into @minutes values (@min)
    end 

    insert into @intervals
    select ([row]-1)/15+1 intervalId, [dayname], min(interval_time) interval_start_time

   > -- **NOTE: This line is the only thing you need to change:**

   , DATEADD(ms, 59998, max(interval_time)) interval_end_time


    from 
    (
        select row_number() over(order by [date]) as [row], [date],  datename(weekday, [date]) [dayname], [date] interval_time
        from @minutes
    ) t 
    group by ([row]-1)/15+1, [dayname]
    order by ([row]-1)/15+1

    return 

end 

 --example of calling it:
 select * from dbo.getDate15MinIntervals('2017-07-14')
```

Then, I am querying your `branch` table (you don't really need the `Date` table, the weekday now you have it in the function but even if not, there's a [DATENAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datename-transact-sql) function in SQL Server, starting with 2008 that you can use.

I would query your table like this:

```
select branchname, [dayname], ISNULL([11:30], 0) as [11:30], ISNULL([11:45], 0) as [11:45], ISNULL([12:00], 0) as [12:00], ISNULL([12:45], 0) as [12:45]
from 
( 
    select intervals.[dayname]
         , b.branchname
         , convert(varchar(5), intervals.interval_start_time, 108) interval_start_time -- for hh:mm format
         , sum(b.ordercount) ordercount
    from branch b cross apply dbo.getDate15MinIntervals(CAST(b.TransactionDate as date)) as intervals
    where b.transactiondate between interval_start_time and interval_end_time
    group by intervals.[dayname], b.branchname, intervals.interval_start_time, intervals.interval_end_time
) t 
pivot ( sum(ordercount) for interval_start_time in ( [11:30], [11:45] , [12:00], [12:45] )) as p
```

Please note I have used in the `PIVOT` function only the intervals I can see in the image you posted, but of course you could write all `15-minute` intervals of the day manually - you would just need to write them once in the `pivot` and once in the `select` statement - or optionally, generate this statement `dynamically`.

Comment: It is not giving me proper count of intervals.Example,  for 11:45 - 11:59 it is not counting properly ,,for 11:59:28  its excluding or may be duplicates because 2 records at 11:59.

Comment: You can replace `BETWEEN` with `>= and <=`, even though `BETWEEN` includes both dates.

Comment: Its still the same output.. any other solution you can think of?

Comment: I think the query is not excluding your data in those intervals. Maybe check the data or edit your question to post the data and expected result (for this interval: 11:45-11:59).

Comment: You are right, the interval_end_time from the function ends at `11:59:00` and the data must be a bit later (`11:59:28` as you say), that's why it is not included. The function returning interval start and interval end needs to be modified slightly, to set the interval end to `11:59:59.997` - which would be the very last moment of that minute. I will edit the function.

Comment: Edited it. I just added milliseconds to the interval end (`DATEADD(ms, 59998, max(interval_time)) interval_end_time`) and you should get the correct results now. I also tested it.