# Calculating average with pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find the average with the help of pivot but not able to find the right solution.

The below is my query:

```
 select branch, ISNULL([11:00], 0) as [11:00],ISNULL([11:15], 0) as 
 [11:15],ISNULL([11:30], 0) as [11:30], ISNULL([11:45], 0) as [11:45], 
 ISNULL([12:00], 0) as [12:00]

from 
( 
select  b.branchname
       ,convert(varchar(5), intervals.interval_start_time, 108) 
       ,sum(b.ordercount) ordercounts
from branch b cross apply dbo.getDate15MinInterval(CAST(b.TransactionDate 
 as date)) as intervals
 where b.TransactionDate >= interval_start_time and b.TransactionDate <= 
 interval_end_time
 and CAST(TransactionDate AS date) IN ('2017-07-01','2017-07-08')

group by DATEPART(WEEKDAY,TransactionDate),b.branchname,intervals.interval_start_time,intervals.interval_end_time
 ) t 
pivot ( avg(ordercounts) for interval_start_time in ( [11:00], [11:15] , 
[11:30], [11:45], [12:00])) as p
```

My original table is:

[image]

Result from the above query is:

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

For 15minuteinterval query, please refer my original post:
[Group data by interval of 15 minutes and use cross tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45096103/group-data-by-interval-of-15-minutes-and-use-cross-tab/45098049?noredirect=1#comment77245822_45098049)

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server does integer arithmetic operations on integers.  The problem is that this is an integer:

```
  sum(b.ordercount) as ordercounts
```

(presumably).

So, just turn it into a floating/fixed point number.  I usually just multiply by 1.0:

```
  sum(b.ordercount)*1.0 as ordercounts
```

But you can be more specific about your types if you like.

Comment: Hi Gordon, that just works for floating. But I am still getting 1 and 8 in the output. It should be 0.5 and 4.

Answer (score 0):

Try casting to float -

```
AVG(CAST(ordercounts AS FLOAT))

SUM(CAST(b.ordercount AS FLOAT)) AS ordercounts
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be done like this:

```
select branchname, [dayname], ISNULL([11:00], 0) as [11:00], AVG(CAST([11:00] as float)) over() [Avg_11:00]
from
(
    select branchname, [dayname], ISNULL([11:00], 0) as [11:00], ISNULL([11:15], 0) as [13:15], ISNULL([11:30], 0) as [11:30], ISNULL([11:45], 0) as [11:45]
    from 
    ( 
        select intervals.[dayname]
             , b.branchname
             , convert(varchar(5), intervals.interval_start_time, 108) interval_start_time -- for hh:mm format
             , sum(b.ordercount) ordercount
        from branch b cross apply dbo.getDate15MinIntervals(CAST(b.TransactionDate as date)) as intervals
        where b.transactiondate between interval_start_time and interval_end_time
        group by intervals.[dayname], b.branchname, intervals.interval_start_time, intervals.interval_end_time
    ) t 
    pivot ( sum(ordercount) for interval_start_time in ( [11:00], [11:15] , [11:30], [11:45] )) as p
) t
group by branchname, [dayname], [11:00]
```

[AVG OVER()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/avg-transact-sql) is valid as of SQL Server 2008.
In this example I only used one interval, but you can extend it to all of the ones you need.

I tried with some sample data from yesterday's answer and it returns values as below:

[image]

Happy coding! :)