# SQL Server - Rounding Times Up/Down to 30 minute intervals

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table:

```
EMP_NO      SHIFT_START_TIME    SHIFT_END_TIME
1234345     09:39               14:39
```

I need to round "up" the start time to the nearest 30 minute interval, and round "down" the end time.

Expected Result

```
EMP_NO      SHIFT_START_TIME    SHIFT_END_TIME
1234345     10:00               14:30
```

Code:

```
SELECT '09:39', '14:39'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [T-SQL: Round to nearest 15 minute interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/830792/t-sql-round-to-nearest-15-minute-interval)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method uses time functions -- calculating the number of minutes since time "0" and then using arithmetic to round up or down to 30 minute intervals:

```
select convert(time, dateadd(minute, ceiling(datediff(minute, 0, start_tm) / 30.0) * 30, 0)),
       convert(time, dateadd(minute, (datediff(minute, 0, end_tm) / 30) * 30, 0))
from (values (convert(time, '09:39'), convert(time, '14:39'))) v(start_tm, end_tm)
```

Comment: This provides the right result for the specified inputs, but is not correct. OP specifically requests `ROUND` for both values, this solution manually chooses `CEILING` and _floor_ via integer math.