# Rounding time in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime, ssms

I need to round time to the nearest quarter in SQL Server.

For example:

- '2016-11-06 13:12:23.000' --> '2016-11-06 13:15:00.000'
- '2016-11-06 13:06:23.000' --> '2016-11-06 13:00:00.000'

I have tried this so far

```
declare @var datetime = '2016-11-06 13:12:35.000'

select @var as original_time

select 
    dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, @var) / 15 * 15, 
    iif(datediff(minute, 0, @var) % 15.0 < 7.5, 0, 
    iif(datediff(minute, 0, @var) % 15.0 < 21.0, 15, 30 ) ))
```

Output:

[image]

The expected result is '2016-11-06 13:15:00.000' but this is the output I get.

I referred to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/830792/t-sql-round-to-nearest-15-minute-interval#:%7E:text=You%20can%20round%20a%20date%20to%20the%20nearest,24%2A4%2C%20the%20number%20of%20quarters%20in%20a%20day.) before the attempt.

Comment: Are you rounding up or down or just to whatever's closest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert to float give the date as a whole number and time as a fraction. Then round to 24 (hours) * 4 (quarters)

```
select CONVERT(DATETIME,ROUND(CONVERT(FLOAT, @var)*24*4,0)/24/4)
```

Change ROUND to CEILING or FLOOR for round up or down

Comment: `float` is a poor choice of data type when dealing with exact values.

Comment: I checked it kept precision to the millisecond

Comment: `float` is an imprecise data type, storing a date and a floating value make **no sense**.

Comment: Its precise enough for this use. A date time is stored internally as 2 integers in SQL Server. 1 for the date, 1 for the time. The time is only precise to 1/300 of a second. So arguably, the DateTime data type is an imprecise way of storing a date/time.

Comment: any way to fix rounded time coming as 06:59 to 07:00

Comment: well, I added a second to the rounded value. thanks for the support