# Round to nearest 15 minute interval

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, rounding

I've seen this question asked and answered for time that is stored as a date, but I have duration of hours and minutes stored as `numeric(4,2)`. For example 2.12, is 2 hours 12 minutes. I need to round that to the nearest 15 minute interval, doing this `(CONVERT([numeric](4,2),round(2.12/(25),(2))*(25)))` doesn't work because it's base 10 and rounds time incorrectly. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

edit: the result I am looking for from the example  would be `2.25`.

For my use case the duration needs to be represented in quarters,

15 minutes  = .25

30 minutes = .50

45 minutes = .75

Comment: I unfortunately don't have that option, I don't have the dates/times just duration.

Comment: Time should be stored in `time` data type, not `numeric`

Comment: @charlieface is that the case when it's not a time but a duration?

Comment: Durations should still be stored as `time` or `datetime` because then you avoid this sort of issue.

Comment: As you are new to the site, I will point out, you are expected to make an attempt yourself, or attempt to adapt the answers provided. Asking for the entire solution isn't what this site is intended for.

Comment: Are you rounding up? Or to the closest 15? i.e. what should 2.02 go to?

Comment: @Joe In the future, it is best to supply at least sample data and desired results.  That will eliminate assumptions and such.

Comment: So long as it's always less than 24 hours, yes it should. At the very least, if you store it in `numeric` store it as hours with decimal fraction, rather than treating the decimal point as a piece of text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally you wouldn't be storing your duration as a decimal - you should be stored as a `time` if always less than 24 hours or a `datetime2` if multiple days are possible.

Convert to a time by converting to a string in acceptable time format. Then use your favourite solution as found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/830792/t-sql-round-to-nearest-15-minute-interval).

```
select
  -- Original Value
   D.[Value]
   -- As Time
   , T.[Time]
   -- As Time Rounded
   , RT.[Time]
   -- As decimal
   , convert(decimal(9,2),datepart(hour,RT.[Time]) + datepart(minute,RT.[Time]) / 60.0)
from (
  -- Test Values
  values (2.12), (2.02), (0.12)
) D ([Value])
cross apply (
  -- Convert to time datatype
  values (convert(time(0), convert(varchar(8),convert(int, D.[Value])) + ':' + substring(convert(varchar(8),D.[Value] - convert(int, D.[Value])),3,8)))
) T ([Time])
cross apply (
  -- Round using your favourite method
  values (convert(time(0), dateadd(minute, round(datediff(minute, 0, T.[Time]) / 15.0, 0) * 15, 0)))
) RT ([Time]);
```

Comment: Thank you Dale, this is helpful. The result I would be hoping to achieve from the example would be 2.25.  For my use case the duration needs to be represented in quarters, 
15 minutes  = .25,
30 minutes = .50,
45 minutes = .75

Comment: @Joe Johns answer is simpler? But thats assuming you are always rounding up, rather than to the nearest.

Comment: Thanks Dale .. I did assume round up.  Most systems I've seen i.e. time cards and/or time & materials round up if not exact.  Either way +1

Comment: @JohnCappelletti a very reasonable assumption :) as soon as you posted I thought you were probably correct - but up to OP.

Answer (score 2):

Here is yet another option

```
declare @YourTable table (duration numeric(4,2))
Insert Into @YourTable values
 ( 2.12 )
,( 1.30 )
,( 1.55 )

Select  Duration 
       ,NewValue = floor(duration) + ceiling(((duration % 1) * 100 / 60 ) * 4) / 4
 From  @YourTable
```

**Results**

```
Duration    NewValue
2.12        2.250000
1.30        1.500000
1.55        2.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't perform any computation on your duration as it is not in base 10 and converting it to base 10 may result in lost in precision (example 2 hour 1 minute in your format is 2.01, converting will be 2.01666666...)

best is to convert it to total minutes and then round it and convert it back to your format

---

```
declare @duration numeric(4,2) = 2.12;

with 
cte1 as
(
    select  tot_mins = (floor(@duration) * 60) 
                     + (@duration * 100) % 100
),
cte2 as
(
    select  *, tot_mins_rounded = round(tot_mins / 15.0, 0) * 15
    from    cte1
)
select  *,
        convert_back_to_your_format = floor(tot_mins_rounded / 60) 
                                    + (tot_mins_rounded % 60) / 100.0
from    cte2
```

Result :

| tot_mins | tot_mins_rounded | convert_back_to_your_format |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 132.00 | 135.000000 | 2.15000000000 |

Comment: Thank you, that does get me total minutes, but I need hours+minutes rounded to the nearest quarter, for example 2.12 (132 minutes) should be 2.25.

Comment: You said `I need to round that to the nearest 15 minute interval`

Comment: To get your "nearest quarter" use `tot_mins_rounded / 60.0`