# Round current datetime down to the last quarter hour in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried this, from [T-SQL: Round to nearest 15 minute interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/830792/t-sql-round-to-nearest-15-minute-interval):

```
SELECT cast(floor(cast(getdate() as float(53))*24*4)/(24*4) as datetime)
```

it works, but sometimes returns something like this

```
2022-01-20 12:14:59.91xx
```

when it should be

```
2022-01-20 12:15:00
```

hopefully this can be solved by a one-liner

Comment: As a side note, the reason you get rounding problems was because of your choice of data type: `float`.

Comment: @Larnu Thank you for your insight. What data type would be appropriate?

Comment: Date and time data types and the date and time functions, like shown in the duplicate. `float` is a base 2 value; it doesn't mix well with base 10 values when they aren't integers.